# JFileChooser and copying files

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I am working on an assignment for class and have a couple questions I was hoping to get help with.  The assignment is a GUI that allows the user to select a file to copy and choose where you'd like to copy the file to.

I've finished the assignment but there were a couple things I wanted to see if I could change...

**When selecting the the source file I want ONLY the name of the source file to show up in the Label but, the program needs the entire path in order to copy the file and every time I tried to switch it to show the file name only the program won't run because it doesn't know where the file is located.  Second question, is there anyway to make the program copy a file automatically as a .bak file...Say the source file is a text file and the user picks a destination folder and hits copy and it saves a file with the same name but a .bak extension?**

I put the code in question in between *** and left the code I was trying to use to display the file name only and commented it out.  Thanks for any help!!

```
public class CopyFile extends JFrame{

private JFileChooser fc;
private JButton copyButton;
private JButton chooseFileButton;
private JButton destinationButton;
private File workingDirectory;
private JLabel sourceLabel;
private JLabel destinationLabel;
private JTextField sourceText;
private JTextField sourceFileText;
private JTextField destinationText;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    CopyFile go = new CopyFile();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(500, 150);
    go.setVisible(true);
}

public CopyFile() {
    super("Copy a text file");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));
    fc = new JFileChooser();

    //Open dialog box inside project folder to make easier to find files
    workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);
    //create labels and buttons for window
    chooseFileButton = new JButton("CHOOSE SOURCE FILE");
    destinationButton = new JButton("DESTINATION FOLDER");
    copyButton = new JButton("COPY FILE");      
    sourceLabel = new JLabel("SOURCE FILE: ");
    sourceText = new JTextField(10);
    sourceText.setEditable(false);
    destinationLabel = new JLabel("DESTINATION: ");
    destinationText = new JTextField(10);

    //add everything to JFrame  
    add(sourceLabel);
    add(sourceText);
    add(chooseFileButton);  
    add(destinationLabel);
    add(destinationText);
    add(destinationButton);
    add(copyButton);

    //Create TheHandler object to add action listeners for the buttons.
    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    chooseFileButton.addActionListener(handler);
    destinationButton.addActionListener(handler);
    copyButton.addActionListener(handler);
}

//Inner class to create action listeners    
private class TheHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int returnVal;
        String selectedFilePath;
        File selectedFile;

******************************************************************************      
        //Selecting a source file and displaying what the user is doing.
        if(event.getSource() == chooseFileButton) {     
            returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            //Set the path for the source file. 
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {  

  /*The two next lines of code are what I was trying to do to get only the
  file name but I get a whole page of errors, mainly I think it's saying no 
  such file exists*/
                //selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //sourceText.setText(selectedFile.getName());   
                selectedFilePath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                sourceText.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }       
        }//end if

******************************************************************************          
        //Handle destination button.
        if(event.getSource() == destinationButton) {
            returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                 selectedFilePath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                destinationText.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }               
        }//end if

        //Handle copy button
        if(event.getSource() == copyButton) {
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceText.getText());
            File destinationFile = new File(destinationText.getText());
            Path sourcePath = sourceFile.toPath();
            Path destinationPath = destinationFile.toPath();        
            try {
                Files.copy(sourcePath,  destinationPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }//end if

    }//end actionPerformed      
}//end TheHandler class
}//end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have to keep the **source** and **destination** file paths as
>   `File`s, not `String`s. Modify your code of `TheHandler` class as
>   follows.

1. Add `selectedSourceFile` and `selectedDestinationFile` local fields.

   ```
   private class TheHandler implements ActionListener {
       private File selectedSourceFile;
       private File selectedDestinationFile;
   ```
2. Update them when selecting files and set file name instead of path to the text fields.

**source file button**

```
        if (event.getSource() == chooseFileButton) {
            returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedSourceFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                sourceText.setText(selectedSourceFile.getName());
            }
        }
```

**destination button**

```
        if (event.getSource() == destinationButton) {
            returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedDestinationFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                destinationText.setText(selectedDestinationFile.getName());
            }
        }
```

3. Use `selectedSourceFile` and `selectedDestinationFile` when copying them.

   ```
       if (event.getSource() == copyButton) {
           Path sourcePath = selectedSourceFile.toPath();
           Path destinationPath = selectedDestinationFile.toPath();
           try {
               Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   ```

> Now you are done the first requirement. You can make backfile when
>   selecting the destination file. So, add your code to make backup file when
>   selecting destination button.

```
        if (event.getSource() == destinationButton) {
            returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedDestinationFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                destinationText.setText(selectedDestinationFile.getName());

                //copy backup
                String name = selectedSourceFile.getName();
                name = selectedSourceFile.getName().substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".bak";
                File destinationFile = new File(selectedDestinationFile.getParentFile(), name);
                try {
                    Files.copy(selectedSourceFile.toPath(), destinationFile.toPath());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Channa, that worked out.  So why did it make a difference that I was using a String to get the file path?

Comment: because strings have not more file operations functions such get file name, get path, get parent path and etc. they are very useful when file operations. so it's better to use file instead of string when working with file operations.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense.  Thanks again!  I have another quick question if you don't mind, I wasn't sure if I should start a new question for a simple question.  I added a JTextArea to display that the file was copied successfully.   However, since I'm using the GridLayout it's not allowing me to change the size of the JTextArea and it's not long enough to display the whole text....Any suggestions?

Comment: put your JTextArea in a JScrollPane then you will be able to view hidden text scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

> When selecting the the source file I want ONLY the name of the source file to show up in the Label but, the program needs the entire path in order to copy the file and every time I tried to switch it to show the file name only the program won't run because it doesn't know where the file is located.

You can use `File#getName`, which will return the name of the file and use this as the text for the label, but maintain a reference to the original `File`.  You shouldn't be taking the text of the label to generate a new `File` reference, just keep a reference to the source `File` and destination `File` and instance fields

> Second question, is there anyway to make the program copy a file automatically as a .bak file...Say the source file is a text file and the user picks a destination folder and hits copy and it saves a file with the same name but a .bak extension?

```
String name = selectedFile.getName();
name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
name += ".bak";
File destinationFile = new File(destinationPath, name);
```

Will change the extension of the `selectedFile` to `.bak`, but you should probably add a check to see if it has an extension to start with

Comment: Hey Mad, thank you.  I understand what you're actually saying but I'm still a little confused.  I'm gonna reread your answer to the first question and see if I can get it to work and report back if I can't get it lol